# Can I use PDO transaction in this way?

Tags: php, pdo

So I want to use PDO transaction in PHP OOP where in the class are multiple insert/update queries.

If I create a new methods in Class like beginTransaction(), commit(), rollback() and I use them afterwards in my code is it okay?

Here is one example:

```
class TestClass
{
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->pdo = $db->DB_CONN();
    }

    public function beginTransaction()
    {
        return $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
    }

    public function commit()
    {
        return $this->pdo->commit();
    }

    public function rollback()
    {
        return $this->pdo->rollback();
    }


    public function insert_one()
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (id,name,text) VALUES (:id, :name, :text)");
        $stmt->execute([":id" => "146",
                        ":name" => "Test Name",
                        ":text" => "Test MSG"]);
    }

    public function insert_two()
    {
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (id,name,text) VALUES (:id, :name, :text)");
        $stmt->execute([":id" => "145",
                        ":name" => "TEST NAME 2",
                        ":text" => "TEST MSG 2"]);
    }

}

$dataBase  = new DataBase;
$testClass = new TestClass($dataBase);

try {
    $testClass->beginTransaction();

    $testClass->insert_two();
    $testClass->insert_one();

    $testClass->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("rolling back.." . $e);
    $testClass->rollBack();
}
```

Its working fine, but I'm not sure if this is a good way to implement it..

Thank you!

Comment: You have a close vote, because your code is not actually accomplishing anything on the one hand and missing context (e.g. the `Database` class) on the other hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work but it's not a good way to implement it.

#### Confusion

*Why* did you create all these methods in the first place? Why don't you use $this->pdo->beginTransaction() right away? What is the reason?

#### Separation of concerns and Code reuse

But even if you want to create such methods, it just *unnatural* to have them in the TestClass. Given there will be TestClass2, you're going to write all these methods again, seriously?

Naturally, all those should go into the Database class.

Besides, Your TestClass should only contain the code related to Test. While all this transaction business is related to the database.

#### Database connection

Calling `$db->DB_CONN()` in the constructor just makes no sense. What if you will have to instantiate two classes? It will create two database connections? What if it will be a hundred? The connection has to be made elsewhere and TestClass should consume an already created $pdo instance.

#### Error handling

There must be no die() on error in any code ever. Your code should allow to handle the error gracefully. Therefore it must be `throw $e;` instead of die.

#### Exception handling

You should catch all exceptions. For the transaction, it doesn't matter, whether it was a PDOException or whatever else error that interrupted the code execution.

#### Logical inconsistency

What's the point in calling $testClass->rollBack() when your script already died?

#### Encapsulation

Why you're writing all this payload in the open? Why not to create a method that encapsulates it?

#### Naming

According to [the standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/), there must be no method names like insert_two() or DB_CONN()

#### The code

So a better version could be like

```
class TestClass
{
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function insertOne()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id,name,text) VALUES (:id, :name, :text)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([":id" => "146",
                        ":name" => "Test Name",
                        ":text" => "Test MSG"]);
    }

    public function insertTwo()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (id,name,text) VALUES (:id, :name, :text)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([":id" => "145",
                        ":name" => "TEST NAME 2",
                        ":text" => "TEST MSG 2"]);
    }
    public function insertAll()
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
            $this->insertTwo();
            $this->insertOne();
            $this->pdo->commit();
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}

$dataBase  = new PDO(...);
$testClass = new TestClass($dataBase);
$testClass->insertAll();
```

#### Code formatting

See, my code example doesn't trigger the horizontal scrolling, making it much easier to read. And it's not a trifle matter. We are writing a code for the programmer. And it must be always comfortable to read.